# Connect to Ejabberd server using Smack on Android emulator

Tags: android, ejabberd, smack

I've started to develop an android chat application using Smack. The server I've been using is Ejabberd 4.2 which I want to connect it on the local machine using the emulator. This is the code to make a connection and print some log text:

```
      try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2");
            DomainBareJid serviceName = JidCreate.domainBareFrom("localhost");
            XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .setUsernameAndPassword(user,pass)
                    .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                    .setXmppDomain(serviceName)
                    .setHostAddress(address)
                    .setPort(5222)
                    .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                    .build();

            AbstractXMPPConnection conn = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
            conn.connect();
            if (conn.isConnected()){
                Log.d(TAG, "connection established");
            }
            conn.login();

            if (conn.isAuthenticated()){
                Log.d(TAG, "connection authorized");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I've used **10.0.2.2** as the localhost domain name for emulator, but it throws ConnectionException.

> SmackException$ConnectionException: The following addresses failed:
>   'null:5222' failed because: /10.0.2.2 exception:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: Windows 8 @MickaëlRémond.

Comment: Did you try using your dev machine network IP?

Comment: Yes, it gives me the wrong address error.

Comment: The current error you have (in the description) means that the emulator cannot connect to your host. Maybe it is your firewall.

Comment: No, it's not about Firewall. I've tried it.